# Where I can find a list of dependencies?

Tags: ros-melodic, rospy, add-dependencies, dependencies, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know where find or what dependencies to use when I will create a package dependencies. It's possible create a depends? For example, in the Tutorial I see rospy, roscpp and std_msgs. Where I can find more and how I can know what dependencies use in my projects? Is there some description about the dependencies?

ROS Melodic
Ubuntu 18.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329235/where-i-can-find-a-list-of-dependencies?/) by [Jose-Araujo](https://answers.ros.org/users/40005/jose-araujo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2019-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package.xml file inside the package that you created contains the information about package dependencies.
This is the place to edit the package dependencies.

---

Originally posted by [Pallav](https://answers.ros.org/users/44188/pallav/) with karma: 26 on 2019-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jose-Araujo](https://answers.ros.org/users/40005/jose-araujo/) on 2019-08-14**:
So, what I want to know is where I can find the list of dependencies in the site of ROS. Because, I know basically three dependencies (rospy, roscpp, std_msgs).

**Comment by [Pallav](https://answers.ros.org/users/44188/pallav/) on 2019-08-18**:
First you need to state an application and see what all available packages are required. Based upon application you might require tf, geometry_msgs, nav_msgs et cetera. Check this ros wiki page: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage

**Comment by [Jose-Araujo](https://answers.ros.org/users/40005/jose-araujo/) on 2019-08-19**:
I think I get it now, thank you very much @Pallav.